# How to deploy H2O flow pojo file in production

Tags: java, azure, spring-mvc, deployment, pojo

How to deploy H2O flow pojo file in production -

We have a pojo file module which we have imported from H2O flow. We need to deploy the pojo file. 
We made a GBM(classification) model using H2O Flow and after exporting the model it gave a POJO file and a jar file, I have made a runnable jar out of the POJO file , but is there anyway to deploy the POJO file to production. 
Can anyone help

Comment: Your description is too simple, even I don't know what you want and what matter with Azure is. Please post more details about what you did on Azure and what issue you got.

Comment: Please see the edited question above.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at the documentation [here](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/productionizing.html).

Also JavaDoc for the class in generated POJO file might be helpful as it has an example of how to compile your POJO for production.